# How to excecute a function for a specific time?

Tags: c#, .net, timer

In my application, I am using socket while receiving acknowledgment.
I have to check my function for certain amount of time (lets say for x no of seconds) for acknowledgment.

if acknowledgment not received then wait for x no. of seconds wait till the given amount of time.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Please show relevant code. What does "close the function" mean?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for `ReceiveTimeout`. Not sure what you mean by *close the function* though.

Comment: Close the function  means I have to stop the execution of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Stop Watch to execute a function for a particular time.

```
//Below code will excecute the code for 10 sec 
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();



 do
 {
  stopWatch.Start();

//perform your Function

    if (result = true)
    {
    stopwatch.reset();
    break;
    } 

    }While (stopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds <= 10));
```